# Are Aang and Zuko related?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

If avatar Aang is basically avatar Roku and Roku is Zuko's great grandfather does that not make Aang Zuko's great grandfather there for they are related?

Comment: "*Reincarnation doesn't work quite like that. Aang is an entirely different person, with different thoughts, experiences, and everything else. He is bonded to every other Avatar to have lived through the Avatar Spirit, which means he is linked with all of them, but they aren't all the same person.*" - https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/ynzm9/are_aang_and_zuko_related/

Comment: +1 @Valorum Likely [relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma#Karma_and_ethicization).

Answer (score 4):

No, each Avatar is their own person. While their souls remain linked in some fashion, their bodies are distinct, as denoted by the fact that each nation takes a turn as having an Avatar. If they were actually related by blood, merely [wiping out the airbenders](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Air_Nomad_Genocide) (as the Fire nation did) would not have stopped the cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Well it’s kind of confusing, Aang technically IS Zuko’s great grandfather, but they’re not related. It’s referred to MANY times in the show that the reincarnation of the avatar ARE the same person, with A different form. This is shown with lines like “Our shared past” and “We are you”. So genetically no, Aang and Zuko aren’t related, but since Aang is Roku, spiritually he is his great-grandfather.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Since this differs from the point of a couple of other responses here you should provide a reference for this.

Answer (score -1):

Only by familial association/marriage, not genetic. 
Aang will be his own Great-Great-Great grandfather. ... Aang is reincarnated Roku. Roku is Zuko's great-grandpa. Therefore, Aang is Zuko's great-grandpa.